# find the last commit where a delete file is still present

Tags: git

I lost a file, because I put it in the .gitignore (at least a month ago ! but I don't know when exactly, so I don't know the precise commit) and I swithched from branches to branches in between.

How can I get it back from the previous commits ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git checkout <commit> <path/to/filename>` will grab the specified file from the specified commit.

Comment: Can I find the last commit where this file is present ? (sorry I edited the question)

Comment: Sure, do `git log -2 -- path/to/filename`

Comment: What is the "-2" please ?

Comment: It shows the last 2 commits that involved that file: the one that deleted the file, and the latest one that contains the file.

Comment: oh ok, great ! Thank you